# Paste grep search from multiple files to a new one

Tags: linux, grep

I have multiple files such as this.

```
filename.log.50
filename.log.49
filename.log.48
...
...
filename.log.2
filename.log.1
```

All of them have content as

```
....connection established
....sending data "Text"
....return ok
....connection closed
```

How could I put into a new file all the 'sending data "Text" lines' from files ending from 30 to 50?
I was doing line by line as this:

```
cat filename.log.50 |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
cat filename.log.49 |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
cat filename.log.48 |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
....
....
```

I was thinking something as this...

```
cat filename.log.5* |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
cat filename.log.4* |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
cat filename.log.3* |grep 'sending data' >> new_file.log
```

But that will include the filename.log.5, filename.log.4, filename.log.3

Comment: You could rename one digit numbers, to two-digit numbers (05 instead of 5). When I return home I 'll post an answer if none exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use this:

```
grep 'sending data' file.log{[34][0-9],50} >> new_file.log
```

Which will match everything from 30 up to 50.

If that does not work to you, then split in two blocks:

```
grep 'sending data' file.log[34][0-9] >> new_file.log
grep 'sending data' file.log50 >> new_file.log
```

`[34][0-9]` matches from `30` to `49`.

Comment: I tried, but it returns this: file.log[34][0-9]: No such file or directory

Comment: Err must be because in fact your files are `filename50`, etc, so that it should be `filename.log[34][0-9]`

Comment: You're right, I was missing the last dot before the numbers! Thank you very much!

Comment: In the new file, all lines have the file name at the begining, do I've to add a flag option in the command to avoid that?

Comment: @tachomi, yes you can use `grep -h`. From `man grep`, "-h, --no-filename, Suppress the prefixing of file names on output".

Comment: Thank you @fedorqui!!! For last, is there a chance to insert all in  inverse mode, I mean, from filename.log.50 to filename.log.30, I put this grep 'sending data' file.log[43][9-0] >> new_file.log but it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a loop instead:

```
for i in {30..50}; do
  grep 'sending data' "filename.log.$i"
done > new_file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple way:

```
seq -f "filename.log.%.f" 50 30 | xargs grep "sending data" > new_file.log
```